# Bridge 2 routers that aren't connected directly to each other

Tags: networking, openwrt

I am trying to figure out how to best set up my home network but I am not sure it is possible to do what I am trying to do. I'll explain my setup first so that it makes so sense when I try to explain my goal.

I have 3 routers in my house. The first router is one supplied by my ISP and it stays in my basement where it supplies a connection for all the Ethernet wiring in the house. Let's call it router A. The second and third and are on different levels of the house and provide WiFi for the house. They are both TP-Link routers running OpenWRT. We can call them router B and C. Every other device in the house is connected via WiFi or through Ethernet via router B or C.

Here is a diagram for further clarification (I don't have the rep to post direct pictures).

[image: Network Diagram]

Router A has little to no customization available but I can't swap it with either of the other 2 routers because it only accepts PPPoe via it's WAN port. At the moment, both routers b and c are connected to router A via LAN ports (rather than their WAN ports). I think this means that they are bridged but I am not sure what the proper term is.

Routers B and C are running OpenWRT and I want to use their advanced firewall features. Since they are both connected using lan ports I want to activate the firewall on Router B and then set Router C to connect "through" Router B. Would this be possible if I set Routers' C gateway to 192.168.1.2 (see diagram for IP's).

Obviously the easier solution would be to purchase another router and I am willing to do that if there is no way to do what I am trying to do.

I can't connect Router's B and C via the WAN port because the devices between the 2 networks won't be able to see each other, which is a must for me since I have a Plex Server running.

Comment: Can you connect C directly to B and then only B to A (or B to C and C to A)?

Comment: Not possible with current house wiring.